# Merge to insert / delete /update entire row without naming EVERY variable

Tags: t-sql, merge, insert, sql-update

I want to do something like

```
use mydb
go

begin tran
merge dbo.aTestTarget as T
using dbo.aTestSource as S
on (T.link = S.link)
when not matched by target and (s.code like '*I%') then
      -- is there a way to do this sort of thing?
      insert (T.*) values (S.*)

when matched and ...
rollback tran
go
```

Is there some way to do this WITHOUT defining EVERY column?  I have a number of tables with 20 to 50 fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. Using the * syntax is a bad practice anyway because it makes for fragile code that will be hard to maintain.

However, in SSMS you can drag&drop the Columns folder under a table into the editor to get a comma separated list of all columns for that table. That makes typing a little easier. :)